# Bootstrap and their JS plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I was working on getting Scrollspy to work. My code had no errors

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".workplease" data-offset="300">
<div class="site-wrapper">
  <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
    <div class="cover-container" >
      <div class="masthead clearfix">
        <div class="inner">
          <h3 class="masthead-brand">Master Sensei</h3>
          <nav class="workplease" role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
            <li><a href="#info">Om filmen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#info2">Produktion</a></li>
            <li><a href="#info3">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
```

but Scrollspy did not work for some reason, until I added

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
```

But the bootstrap documentation says

> Plugins can be included individually (using Bootstrap's individual *.js files), or all at once (using bootstrap.js or the minified bootstrap.min.js).

Even though I already had the *bootstrap.min.js* in my index file.
isn't Scrollspy included in the *bootstrap.min.js*, and unnecessary for me to load individually, or am I mistaken?

Here is my whole script section in my index file. Maybe it has something to do with the order of things?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./index_files/docs.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="./index_files/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
```

Comment: How are you including the Bootstrap CSS? Ideally, it should be `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css`.

Comment: Here is my bootstrap.min.css
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Edit your question, don't put code in the comments. What's with that semi-colon in the `<link>` tag? Also, how are you implementing ScrollSpy? Where's the rest of your code?

Comment: Try to build a js fiddle including all your references without adding scrollspy.js, also you are mixing bootstrap versions.

Comment: @PatrickLC Well... I just did, and it works in Jfiddle without the scrollspy.js, but apparently not on my computer (without the file, that is) https://jsfiddle.net/qqqvmLog/

Comment: Perhaps you have something different in your local example, any different js linked? Could you check if there any error shows up using your browser developer tools?

Comment: @PatrickLC no errors in the console, already checked. All the code I have is in the fiddle. I've read a lot of questions on here with people not being able to make it work, and why it's working on JSfiddle but not on my machine, is beyond me

Comment: Make sure you are using same version of bootstrap's js and css files.